# What the difference is here? Are you seeing ? VS Do you see?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

Are you seening family members arriving at the hospital to find some of the miners? ( exact quote from BBC presenter asking someone over the phone )

Do you see .......

Difference in meaning not grammar.

Answer (score 1):

The real question here is "What do you see?". The reporter is controlling the interview by asking a leading question: that is a question with some of the answer in it already.

> "Are you seeing family members arriving at the hospital to find some of the miners?"

vs

> "Do you see family members arriving at the hospital to find some of the miners?"

I don't have all the context here, but I belive the reporter choose the first construction to better tell a story. The reporters job is to no only find out the details of what is happening but to be able to present them in a way that the listeners will understand and feel.

**"Are you seeing" lets the listener better imagine the scene**. This makes for a better story.